# I want to use a <apex:commandLink> inside of a <apex:component>

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

Well, the titlle says it all !

I need to use the  inside of a custom visualforce component.

Any help is appreciated !

Thank you so much !

Comment: I posted an answer kind of guessing the need you were going for.  Was I right that you're trying to call an action inside a component passed into it by the hosting page/component?

Answer (score 0):

There is a type called ApexPages.Action that can be used in an apex:attribute of your component.  The one limitation I've noticed is you can't name that attribute "action" or it won't function.

Here is an example:

Component:

```
    <apex:commandButton action="{!someaction}" value="test"/>
</apex:component>
```

The page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="test" columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <c:actiontest someaction="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```